# How to send other data when connected socket TcpClient in WindowsForms using NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcpclient, networkstream

I have a connection that using tcpclient, to send and receive data between server and client . The application is written on the basis of Window Form, I have used BackgroundWorker to handle parallel running tasks. The program runs normally when i clicked Start button, it receives data handshake from the client side and sends the data back to the client. I want to add a function to send new content from textbox, like sample fill up data to Textbox1 and click Send button, it will be sent to the client from server in parallel during the connection between server and client. But when I add this, I get an error returning "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream" at this line "stream.Write(msg_byte, 0, msg_byte.Length);" and data is not sent. What did I do wrong, can you point it out to me. This is my snipped code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw;
        static NetworkStream stream = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }

        private void _startServer(string _ip, int _port)
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(_ip), _port);
                server.Start();
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
                String data = null;
                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    txt_log.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        txt_log.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Connnected " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "\r\n");
                    }));
                    data = null;
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                    int i;
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        txt_log.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            txt_log.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Received: " + data + "\r\n");
                        }));
                     
                        data = data.ToUpper();
                        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        txt_log.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            txt_log.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Sent: " + data + "\r\n");
                        }));                
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("_startServer: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("completed");
        }

        void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!bw.CancellationPending)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("processing");
            }
        }

        void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            _startServer("192.168.10.15", 4444);
            bw.ReportProgress(100);
        }

        private void bt_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bw.IsBusy)
            {
                bw.CancelAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                txt_log.Clear();
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void bt_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bw.CancelAsync();
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void bt_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string msg_send = txt_msg.Text;
            byte[] msg_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg_send);
            
            while (true)
            {
                stream.Write(msg_byte, 0, msg_byte.Length);
                txt_log.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    txt_log.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Sent new data: " + msg_send + "\r\n");
                })); 
                
                string msg_receive = null;
                byte[] temp_byte = new byte[1024];
                stream.Read(temp_byte, 0, temp_byte.Length);
                msg_receive = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(temp_byte);
                txt_log.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    txt_log.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Received new data: " + msg_receive + "\r\n");
                }));
            }   
        }


    }
}
```

The situation is open connection to server from the client, on the one hand, always keep the connection from the server to the client by sending temporary data continuously, like the client side always sending "are you there?" , the server always replied "ok, here I am" when get signal data temp from client, this way is working good for me, no issue. On the other hand, I would like to have other signals sent from the server to the client according to what the user enters into the Textbox component, i just try and thinking the best way to do it.

After some change, make code is easier to look

```
private string IsRealData(byte[] data)
{
    string txt = "";
    if (data[10] == 100)
        txt = "are you there?";
    else
        txt = "NOTHING";
    return txt;
}

private void _startServer(string _ip, int _port)
{
    TcpListener server = null;
    try
    {
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(_ip), _port);
        server.Start();
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            String data = null;
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i;
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                byte[] bytes_real = new byte[i];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, bytes_real, 0, i);
                if (IsRealData(bytes_real) == "are you there?") 
                {        
                    string _msg_reply = "ok, here I am";
                    byte[] reply = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_msg_reply);         
                    stream.Write(reply, 0, reply.Length);  ///sent real data to client
                    txt_log.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        txt_log.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff tt") + " Sent: " + _msg_reply + "\r\n");
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    data = data.ToUpper();
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length); ///sent temporary data to client
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("_startServer: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private async Task Start_Server()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _startServer("192.168.10.15", 4444);
    });
}

private void bt_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Start_Server();
}

private void bt_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = txt_msg.Text;
    ////how to send content parallel when user input from Textbox component
}
```

Thanks you all.

Comment: I think the connection between the client and the server has closed. For such purpose it would be good to use Socket connection.

Comment: You are using a NetworkStream that uses the end of the stream is NULL not zero.  So change following : while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) to test for null.  You are not receiving the entire stream.  You are get an underrun because you are reading faster than the data is being received.  There is more data and testing for null will become true when ALL the data is being received.

Comment: Side note: `async` `await` is much easier than messing with the ancient `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: @BokiliProduction , look like my add more explain , if you have any idea resolve it before.

Comment: @jdweng , i think other on hand need to retry, see my case supplement on the question

Comment: @Charlieface ,hm, let me try something else from your advice. but need to find somehow done it before, any proof from you i appreciate for it.

Comment: You have two different `stream` variables, one is a field and the other a local variable.

Comment: @Charlieface, look like it will not working in this case , right ?

Comment: You need to create an application layer so you can send different commands and get back different results.  TCPClient is a transport layer to send/receive data.

Comment: Are you getting any messages in the messagebox.  The _startServer: message will display when any errors occur while receiving messages and close the connection.

Comment: Are you maybe in stack with while (true) in bt_send_Click? Where is break or return?
How long have you been working with C#?

Comment: @jdweng , I am update some code to look easier, this code is working smoothly without Send button. After that, I don't know how to demonstrate in Send button.

Comment: @BokiliProduction sorry about that, I quite confusing and stuck for this case, I don't know how to build Send button include that, can you look my update code to easier.

Comment: Use Async Listener.  The accept method contain the socket for each new connection.  From the socket you can get the remote endpoint (ip address).  You can make a list of connections so you can distinguish between connections by the ip address.

Comment: @jdweng After pressing the Start button, connecting the client to the server, I check with the command line `netstat -a -n` and see socket ESTABLISHED connecting from the client's random port 192.168.10.100 after each press of the Start button head to the server 192.168.10.15 port 4444. As you said, I need access the list connection ESTABLISHED by `IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpListeners();`, After that get this current socket connected and do send data in this socket, right ?

Comment: You get the endpoints which contains the source and destination IP addresses.  Not the socket.  To send data you need the socket.  The socket owns the endpoints.  You need the socket to send data.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need a persistent connection?

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid , This is what I said above, I need to keep connection and receive info from the client continuously, it's like a type of auto-answer message center, the client always sends question and get answer info from the server, The server receives info and automatically responds. On the other hand, I want the server to send messages from Textbox component. Probably this way run parallel. I have completed the part that is always receiving messages from the client side and responding, the rest is the Send button written specifically, I don't know how to trigger it.

Comment: @Headshot I think I should write you the code how it works in practice with the chat server. Any communication must run in the background, and what you show in the application must be the main thread (UI). I recommend doing this in a Thread with "while(boolean isConnected){...}" instead of a BackgroundWorker. It's easier for you, to begin with. If you don't succeed with this, tell me, and in the answer I will write an example of .Net Framework code in C#, for the server and the client.

Comment: @Headshot:  It seems that this type of behavior has the potential to be used by a hacker to avoid detection during a data breach.

Comment: @BokiliProduction ,we can discuss via message when you have available time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debug and enhancement, now it' working for me. Notify that, i just quite change in lasted code, based on the connection socket between server and client is established, give this socket object and using send/receive. That's it.

```
private TcpClient client;
 
 private async void _startServer(string _ip, int _port)
{
    //code in here
    client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
    //code in here
}

private async Task Start_Server()
{
        //code in here
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}

private async void bt_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Start_Server();
}

private async Task SendMsg(string msg)
{
    //code in here using SendAsync & ReceiveAsync
    return;
}

private async void bt_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code in here
    await SendMsg(txt_msg.Text);
}
```

Thank you all for advice.

Comment: Nice. Do your research and be persistent.